# Regex match where part of string doesn't contain a character

Tags: regex

I need a regexp that I want to match against several different strings.

The regex should retrieve a match for this string:

```
http://www.domain.com/category
```

But not for this:

```
http://www.domain.com/category/sports
```

or

```
http://www.domain.com/category/sportsmanship
```

I have tried the following regex but it doesn't really want to work:

```
/categ.*?^((?!sports).)*$/g
```

Comment: Could you be more clear: Do you want to avoid the substring "sports" or the "sports" directory? In other words, is for example "sportsmanship" allowed?

Comment: I want to avoid the sports directory entirely. Clarification added in the question. I know there are similar questions on stackoverflow but I haven't been able to understand the answers enough to implement them in my particular case.

Comment: What do you want matched in `http://www.domain.com/category/toys`? All of `category/toys`?  What about `http://www.domain.com/category/people/sports`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write

```
/\/categ[^\/]*(?:\/(?!sports)[^\/]*)*$/
```

In this pattern, the negative lookahead checks after each slashes if the string "sports" doesn't follow.

Note: if you have to deal with long paths that contains the string "sports" relativly often, you can try this variant to speed up the pattern:

```
/\/categ(?=([^\/]*))\1(?:\/(?!sports)(?=([^\/]*))\2)*$/
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this regex:

```
.*/category(?!/sports).*
```

**[Working demo](http://regex101.com/r/iQ6vY5/1)**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't want to match the line which contains the string `sports` at the last. If yes then you could try the below regex,

```
^.*?categ(?:(?!sports).)*$
```

The problem with your regex is `.*?^`. `^` asserts that we are at the start of a line.